# Java: picocli: How to provide argument to command without naming it?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, picocli

Is it possible to provide argument to @CommandLine.Command without explicitly naming the argument in `picocli`?

As example the following command can be invoked as: `open n 1`. However, I would like to be able to invoke the command as `open 1`.

```
@CommandLine.Command(name = "open",
    mixinStandardHelpOptions = true,
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Open note")
@Getter
@ToString
public class OpenCommand implements Runnable {
    @CommandLine.ParentCommand TopLevelCommand parent;


    @CommandLine.Option(names = {"number", "n"}, description = "Number of note to open")
    private Integer number;


    public void run() {

        System.out.println(String.format("Number of note that will be opened: " + number));
    }
}
```

Comment: Place the commands in quotation marks. `"open n 1" "open 1"` are two different command line arguments on the same command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picocli offers the `@Parameters` annotation for [positional parameters](https://picocli.info/#_positional_parameters), in addition to the `@Option` annotation, which is for [named parameters](https://picocli.info/#_options).

If you use the `@Parameters` annotation for the number, instead of `@Option(names = "n")`, then end users can invoke the command as `open 1`.

That is a fairly minimal change, the resulting code could look like this:

```java
@CommandLine.Command(name = "open",
    mixinStandardHelpOptions = true,
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Open note")
@Getter
@ToString
public class OpenCommand implements Runnable {
    @CommandLine.ParentCommand TopLevelCommand parent;

    @CommandLine.Parameters(description = "Number of notes to open")
    private Integer number;

    public void run() {
        System.out.printf("Number of notes that will be opened: %s%n", number);
    }
}
```